# Нужен случайный выбор элементов матрицы

Tags: c++, случайные-числа

суть расположения дерева это в массиве строк рандомно написать символы.

вот инициализация карты:

```
const int H = 16;
const int W = 150;

std::string TileMap[H]
{
    "C                                                                                                                                                   C",
    "C                                                                                                                                                   C",
    "C                                                                                                                                                   C",
    "C                                                                                                                                                   C",
    "C                                                                                                                                                   C",
    "C                                                                                                                                                   C",
    "C                                                                                                                                                   C",
    "C                                    ==========================================================                                                     C",
    "C                                                                                                                                                   C",
    "=====================================================================================================================================================",
    "CCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCC",
    "CCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCC",
    "CCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCC",
    "CCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCC",
    "CCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCC",
    "CCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCC",
};
```

вот моя попытка сделать рандомную генерацию:

```
int RandomHeightTree;
bool testCoord = true;

void RandomTree(int count) //15
{
    int randPos;
    for(int i=0;i<count;++i)
    {
        RandomHeightTree = 3 + rand() % 3; //высота дерева

        randPos = rand() % 140 + 3; //позиция дерева

        for(int j = 1;j < 8; ++j)
        {
            if(TileMap[j][randPos]!=' ')
            {
                std::cout<<"\""<<TileMap[j][randPos]<<"\"\n";//DEBUG
                std::cout<<"\""<<j<<"\" "<<"\""<<randPos<<"\"\n\n";//DEBUG
                testCoord=false;//не ставить дерево!
            }            
        }

        if(testCoord) //если можно ставить дерево
        {
            std::cout<<RandomHeightTree<<": "<<randPos<<"\n\n"; //DEBUG
            TileMap[RandomHeightTree-1][randPos] = 'L'; //ставим верхушку дерева
            for(;RandomHeightTree<=8;RandomHeightTree++) //ставим все дерево
            {
                TileMap[RandomHeightTree][randPos] = 'T'; //ставим
            }
        }
    } 
}
```

при одних попытках у меня сажались 0-3 деревьев, при других программа зависала, и я перезагружал пк.

подскажите плиииз как написать эту функцию правильно, главное надо чтобы деревья росли если над ними нет ничего

Comment: Я решил по названию, что имеется в виду генерация структур "дерево".

Comment: какая разница, надо в массив строк это поместить рандомно

Comment: Это совершенно разные задачи. Принципиально разные. С деревьями - это то же, что генерация правильных скобочных последовательностей, напритмер.

Answer (score 1):

Проще использовать матрицу символов, а не массив строк. Тогда всё что нужно делать: сгенерировать 2 числа в границах матрицы с помощью `std::uniform_int_distribution(low, high)`, проверить за константное время нужные вам условия (чтобы сверху не было ничего, достаточно проверить элемент матрицы выше сгенерированного), если всё ок, то записывать символ дерева, иначе снова сгенерировать координаты.

Comment: логично, но я же так и делаю, только генерацию случайных чисел юзаю. Если использую оператор GOTO, то у меня зависание системы и тока перезагружать

Comment: Матрица символов - массив строк ... печаль